# What is the minimum paper size that an HP Inkjet 9025 will print on both sides?

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, paper, hp

The printer supports, for example, 3x5 index cards, but it will not print on both sides of paper this small. It does so with no issue for larger paper sizes.

Why won’t it print on both sides of smaller paper sizes, and what is the smallest size where this is supported?

Comment: I am pretty sure that even tho the printer doesn't support auto duplex printing on small formfactors, you could simply print one side and flip the paper manually.

Comment: “Why won’t it print on both sides of smaller paper sizes, and what is the smallest size where this is supported?” - The only answer to this question is It wasn’t designed to do so

Comment: I am asking this question because I think this info should be available. I know there are other ways to do the same thing, but the printer said it supports small paper sizes and duplex printing. It would be nice to know that it does not support duplex printing for all paper sizes, and where the cutoff is.

Comment: My car supports going 120+mph AND supports going in reverse.  That doesn't mean that it can go 120+mph in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

With a duplexer the paper path is significantly more complex than for simplex printing. Consider that the paper has to be turned around for the second side, yet has to be kept under full control at all times. That is why most manufacturers design a printer so that duplexing is only available for "standard" paper sizes such as A4 and Letter. Also because of the paper path complexity, the paper weight is usually also restricted to a very narrow range (80-100 gsm, bond).

For duplexing, the [specs for your printer](https://support.hp.com/id-en/document/c06237775#AbT11) specifically state "Letter; executive; Not supported for borderless photo".